# 0x000000C4 error on Windows Server 2012 R2 installation

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-installation

I want to install Windows Server 2012R2 on my Dell CS24-SC over USB. It boots successfully from the USB disk. The Windows logo appears and the following error shows up.

```
Need to restart
Hold down the power button
error code:0x000000C4

Parameters:
0x00...091
0x00...00F
0xFFFFF80159BCCA80
0x000...0
```

Comment: Does the BIOS for your PowerEdge CS 24-sc have an option to disable/enable the [NX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) or DX flags? I seem to recall windows 8/server 2012 needed that feature. (otoh, I would expect the installer to check for that before attempting to install the OS).

Comment: I will check that and I 'm going to do a bios update i think that can help

Answer (score 0):

Having an error in the early beginning of the installation means that you have a hardware issue, or incompatible hardware.
First, make sure the files in the USB are not damaged.
Then, you may need to add the RAID drivers for your server to the installation files.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is slightly different to the problem you experienced, but I had the same problem when using Windows 2012 on VirtualBox, and saw the others with Windows 8.1 [were also having the same problem](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-error-0x000000c4-unable-to-install-windows-8-1-using-virtualization).

To cure it, I had to [set the `CMPXCHG16B` flag](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10792):

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" setextradata "My VM Name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

You can also [set it globally](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11899) if required:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" setextradata global VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

I also had to go into the BIOS and change `Memory Protection` from `Disabled` to `Enabled` to solve the problem, so there may be a connection there with your issue.